# number of possible integral solutions

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I am trying to find number of possible integral solutions of this equation but can't figure out the correct formula -
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ....\mbox{ n-terms } = x$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$... can hold values from $[0,9]$.

Comment: If you know generating functions, then you could use the coefficient of $t^x$ in $(1+t+t^4+t^9+t^{16}+t^{25}+t^{36}+t^{49}+t^{64}+t^{81})^n$.  I, however, suspect that this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: how will you calculate the coefficient of $$t^x$$, can u please elaborate

Comment: Michael Burr what if $x=26=0^2+1^2+5^2$

Comment: What do you mean by the "number of possible integral solutions"? Do you mean the number of values of $x$? The number of distinct solutions in $a,b,c,\ldots$ for a given $x$ or for all $x$'s? If the latter, do you consider $(0,1,\ldots)$ the same as $(1,0,\ldots)$? And so on. The question is too vague as is.

Comment: yeah 0,1 and 1,0 are different

Comment: @ArchisWelankar That would correspond to $t^{0^2}\cdot t^{1^2}\cdot t^{5^2}=1\cdot t\cdot t^{25}=t^{26}$.

Comment: You answered only one of my questions. The others?

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult task, already for n=2 ! 
re.

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/background/countingLecture/intro/intro/index.php